# Making Multiple Files in Java

Tags: java, file

I'm having trouble making multiple files with Java. I want it to make n number of identical files that will be placed in a defined directory. For some reason, right now it will make 1 file and then keep making new files with the name of the first file made, which basically refreshes the file. I think it may happen because it is not updating my global name variable. Here's my code so far:

```
import java.io.*;


public class Filemaker{
    //defining our global variables here

    static String dir = "/Users/name/Desktop/foldername/"; //the directory we will place the file in
    static String ext = ".txt"; //defining our extension type here
    static int i = 1; //our name variable (we start with 1 so our first file name wont be '0')
    static String s1 = "" + i; //converting our name variable type from an integer to a string 
    static String finName = dir + s1 + ext; //making our full filename
    static String content = "Hello World";


    public static void create(){  //Actually creates the files 

        try {
            BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(finName)); //tell it what to call the file
            out.write(content); //our file's content 
            out.close();

            System.out.println("File Made."); //just to reassure us that what we wanted, happened
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Didn't work");
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args){

        int x = 0;

        while(x <= 10){ //this will make 11 files in numerical order
            i++; 
            Filemaker.create();
            x++;
        }
    }
}
```

Just see if you can find any errors in my code that would be causing this to happen.

Answer (score 2):

You set `finName` once, when it is initialized.  Instead, you should update it in your `create()` function.  For example:

```
public static void create(){  //Actually creates the files 
    String finName = dir + i + ext; 
    try {
        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(finName)); //tell it what to call the file
        out.write(content); //our file's content 
        out.close();

        System.out.println("File Made."); //just to reassure us that what we wanted, happened
    } catch (IOException e) {

        System.out.println("Didn't work");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you are using your `i` variable in the static definition of your `s1` variable. This looks odd to me and makes me think that you're expecting that to be redefined again and again.

Instead, redefine your s1 variable inside your `create()` function so that it actually increments.

Also, in the future, when troubleshooting problems like this, you can use `System.out.println()` statements to print output to the console to trace execution of your program. For more advanced needs, use a logging solution or your IDE's debugger to trace the program execution and insert breakpoints.

Comment: Thank you, this really helped! Sorry for my lack of debugging habits, I'm new at non web development/programming.

Comment: No worries, I just thought that might be a helpful tip for you. Without a debugger, I'm useless ;)

Answer (score 0):

String are immutable so `finName` is never change after the first initialization.

In your create method you have to recreate your file path.